# How map 2 fields to the same Many to Many association?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

Have a Spring JPA application:

For one use case, I would like to read all the students data in to a set of Student as in the first Set below (CourseRepository.findAll()) - this is used for just reading students associated with a Course.

For a second use case I would like to read & update the students set using just the Student UUIDs (as this is significantly faster avoiding many joins/cascades) - as in the second Set below - this is used just for adding or deleting Students to a Course.

```
@Entity
@Table(...)
public class Course {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST})
   @JoinTable(
       schema = "...",
       name = "...",
       joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "course_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
       inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
   )
   private Set<Student> students = new java.util.HashSet<>();

   @ManyToMany
   @JoinTable(
       schema = "...",
       name = "...",
       joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "course_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
       inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
    )
   private Set<UUID> students = new java.util.HashSet<>();
   ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    private String name;
...
}

@Repository
public interface CourseRepository extends JpaRepository<Course, UUID> {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should model your many-to-many association as two one-to-many associations instead as that is what you will eventually require anyway. This way, an assignment can be done by simply persisting this new `CourseStudentAssignment` entity.

```
@Entity
public class CourseStudentAssignment {
    @EmbeddedId
    CourseStudentAssignmentId id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @MapsId("courseId")
    Course course;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @MapsId("studentId")
    Student student;

}
@Embeddable
public class CourseStudentAssignmentId {
    UUID courseId;
    UUID studentId;
}
@Entity
@Table(...)
public class Course {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST})
   private Set<CourseStudentAssignment> studentAssignments = new java.util.HashSet<>();

}
@Entity
@Table(...)
public class Student {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST})
   private Set<CourseStudentAssignment> courseAssignments = new java.util.HashSet<>();

}
```